# PHP WideImage - performance issues

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I'm having serious performance issues using PHP's WideImage library - http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/.  Loading a 2.2 MB .png file with WideImage::load() has a peak memory usage of 93 MB !  Also, loading, resizing, and writing to the filesystem of a 750 KB .jpg takes almost 30 seconds.  I've run these benchmarks on two different servers with similar results.

Has anyone else run into these problems?  Is it just WideImage being a resource hog?  If I rewrite my image processing with straight GD, instead of WideImage, can I expect better performance, or about the same?  I know PHP is not the best language for image manipulation, but I'd rather not have to compile something in C and then call it from PHP :(

Thanks for your time - Andy

Comment: What is your problem? It seems to work. How often do you do this resizing with around 93 MB memory? Only once per image? I also think 93 MB is ok for manipulating large images no matter what library or language.

Comment: Really?  93MB of memory to manipulate a 2.2MB image?  30 seconds to resize a jpg under 1MB and write it to the filesystem?  There's no way that kind of performance will fly in production, especially on a hosting environment where PHP is allocated limited memory.  I can't expect a user to get up and make tea while they wait for their jpg to resize.

I've seen a lot of PHP code that does this kind of thing faster and leaner, most recently in a WordPress plugin I was working with.  I guess I'll rewrite the routine with straight GD and compare performance.

Comment: Since we don't know anything about the system/CPU...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran some simplified benchmarks and I think I figured it out.  WideImage's resize method isn't persistent.  Example:

```
$image = WideImage::load('path/to/file.png');
$image->getWidth();   <-- lets say that returns a width of 2000 pixels
$image->resize(100, 100);
$image->getWidth();   <-- that will still return a width of 2000 pixels, the original $image has not been altered
```

WideImage operations return a new instance of image and leaves the previous image intact, so to get the result of the operation you need to assign it to a variable:

```
$image = WideImage::load('path/to/file.png');
$image->getWidth();        // 2000 px
$resizedImage = $image->resize(100, 100);
$image->getWidth();        // still 2000 px
$resizedImage->getWidth(); // 100 px
```

So I was moving around images that were a lot larger than I thought, as my resize method wasn't actually altering my source image.

Comment: As an aside, I've learned PHP's memory usage can vary DRASTICALLY between images, even when they have the same size and file format.  I have a 2.2MB .jpg that peaks at 71MB of memory usage when resizing, but a 4MB .jpg that peaks at only 32MB.  No idea why.

Comment: As another aside, I determined WideImage adds minimal overhead to image processing.  The largest image I tried used 90.4MB of memory when using pure GD functions and 92.7MB when using WideImage.   Hopefully all this helps someone who stumbles across this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use custom solution. WideImage possibly has some performance issues. Here is interesting investigation [WideImage performance and memory issues](http://starikovs.com/2012/09/17/wideimage-performance-issues/).